# Excel CountIf formula trouble

Tags: excel, vlookup, countif

im working on a project where i need to use the countif formula to work out how many of the same date are in a table, and the compare the quantity of dates, to the quantity of 'offloads', trouble is there are sometimes a 'cancellation' in the column that 'offloads' can be found in.
Basically if the first countif returns 3, it needs to verify that 3 'offloads' took place, and not 2 'offloads' and 1 'cancellation'

so far the following works for returning the first countif, but i've not implemented the verification stage to the below formulae.

```
=IF(D5="","",IF(H5=" Non Chargeable",0,IF(OR(D5="Cancelled ",D5="Mobilisation",D5="Machine Hire"),VLOOKUP(D5,
'Drop Downs and Misc'!$B$3:$D$8,3,FALSE),IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B5)<=2,'Drop Downs and Misc'!$G$4,IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B5)=3,
'Drop Downs and Misc'!$G$5,IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B5)=4,'Drop Downs and Misc'!$G$6,IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B5)=5,'Drop Downs and 
Misc'!$G$7,0)))))))
```

last night i was thinking about if i could use vlookup to verify that there are the same amount of 'offloads' as there are dates in column B. One option was using the countif to count column D (where the offloads/cancellations are written), however the range would be D:D and not the same range that the dates are found in B:B. Using D:D would search the whole column for quantities of 'offloads', this is the route of my issue

Any help would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: I would split this and test each part separately as a first step.

Comment: the above already works and testing is complete, but i need some fresh ideas on how to add the verification stage

Comment: It would help to see your data structure.